# MGSplitView Controller frame change

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I am using `MGSplitViewController`. Now, I don't want split view to full screen.

Is it possible to change the frame of `MGSplitViewController` ?

Thanks

Comment: It is definitely possible, but it'll be a lot of work (you can try manipulating the frames being set in `MGSplitViewController`). Since `MGSplitViewController` was designed for full screen use, it'd be better to use your own controllers, I think.

Answer (score 2):

In your `MGSplitViewController.m` file you can find method called

`- (void)layoutSubviewsForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)theOrientation withAnimation:(BOOL)animate`

in this method you can modify the frame

For example:-

`// Layout the master, divider and detail views.

```
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0, 70, width, height);
UIViewController *controller;`
```